# Agregar un punto para diferenciar entre miles en linux

Tags: python, linux

El código de debajo me sirve si levanto la pagina en windows, pero en linux me tira error, como podría agregar el punto para los miles sin utilizar la funcion locale.
**Les dejo mi código**

```
    # Obtener la configuración regional actual
original_locale = locale.getlocale()

# Cambiar la configuración regional a "es_AR"
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_AR')

for cliente in clientes:
    cliente.saldo = locale.format_string('%.2f', cliente.saldo, grouping=True)
    
# Restaurar la configuración regional original
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, original_locale)
```

Comment: CUál es el contenido de `clientes`?

Comment: el atributo que quisiera modificar es cliente.saldo

Comment: Cuál es el contenido de `clientes`, incluyendo el atributo `saldo`. Datos de prueba, por favor. Hay una interacción no deseada entre el locale de tu máquina y el contenido de la variable. Entonces, incluye contenido de ejemplo de `clientes` y tendrás la solución, comenzando por la respuesta que ya tienes

Comment: "pero en linux me tira error", sin decir el mensaje de error exacto o describir bien la situación es como llegar por primera vez con un médico y decir _en Lima me siento bien, pero en Buenos Aires me duele_, sin mas contexto, y esperar que el médico te de un diagnóstico y una receta. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es Python, si no que distintos sistemas operativos incluyen los `locales` o lenguajes que necesitan, y no coincidirán unos con otros. Más información al respecto: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/955986/1545868) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55532672/1545868).

Si falta el lenguaje, en Python obtendrás el error: `unsupported locale setting`

Ejecuta en el shell de linux para obtener las localizaciones instaladas:

```
> locale -a
```

Es posible que puedas añadir más localizaciones:
Distros [badadas en Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server), [basadas en RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/assembly_using-langpacks_configuring-basic-system-settings)

---

Omitiendo los locales y cuestiones más invasivas al SO, puedes obtener una cadena del número, formateado con separador de miles y 2 dígitos decimales, usando [f strings](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+f+strings). Entonces, en vez de:

```py
cliente.saldo = locale.format_string('%.2f', ...)
```

Elimina todo lo que tenga que ver con `locale.*` y cambia esa línea por:

```py
cliente.saldo = f'{cliente.saldo:,.2f}' # (*)
# Salida de ejemplo: 12,563.52
```

(*) Sugeriría no sobreescribas la propiedad numérica `cliente.saldo` con una cadena, pero ya esa es otra cuestión aparte. Si lo quieres al contrario, el separador punto y el decimal coma, ya tienes la cadena base, ahora podrías hacer un `replace` de esos símbolos.